# Nombre del dia actual en sentencia MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas tardes Compañeros, lo que deseo es lo siguiente:
Desde un input en php buscar un ID el cual me devuelva 6 campos de esa tabla, en cada uno ira el nombre de un día de la semana, y hacer una comparación de que si HOY() es igual a uno de esos seis campos tengo esta sentencia:

```
        $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$labusqueda%' AND curdate() < final AND date_add(NOW()) LIKE 'thursday' ";
```

El campo %labusqueda ya me arroja un resultado y funciona perfectamente si lo dejo hasta el Where AND curdate() < final después quiero condicionar al comparar el día mencionado en la tabla ejemplo (Lunes ó Monday) con el día actual del sistema entonces  Puse thursday pero ahí deseo poner una variable la cual mandaré a llamar desde una consulta anterior.

Comment: AND date_add(NOW()) que quiere decir? porque esa funcion es para sumar algo a una fecha...

Comment: Esa es la parte erronea de la sentencia, ahi es donde necesito poner "AND 'Funcion para llamar el nombre del dia de hoy en sistema" LIKE VARIABLE CON EL NOMBRE DEL DIA, espero darme a entender, gracias por tu ayyuda!

Comment: algo asi como dayname??? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

Comment: Si quieres filtrar por el nombre de un día no necesitas  `LIKE`, puedes hacer algo como: `WHERE ... AND curdate() < final AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = 'THURSDAY'` aquí usamos `DAYNAME` y ponemos todo en mayúscula con `UCASE` para evitar sorpresas. Eso sí, debes cuidar que el dato también sea recibido en mayúscula. O, puede ser también `LCASE` en vez de `UCASE`, sea lo que sea, debes asegurar que el dato esté en minúscula o mayúscula según el estilo por el que te decidas.

Comment: A @gbianchi y @A.Cedano , millones de gracias ya quedo perfecto asi!           **        $consulta2 = "INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` (`idPagoCliente`, `idCliente`, `idTipoPeriodo`, `inicio`, `final`,  `costo`) select * FROM pagosclientes  where idCliente like '%$labusqueda%' AND curdate() < final AND UCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = 'THURSDAY' ";
**

Comment: Lo pones como respuesta @A.Cedano? no encontre como sacar el nombre trivialmente en google...

Comment: La formula de A.Cedano fue la que me dio  a como queria, igualmente @gbianchi estoy muy agradecido con tu ayuda por que me guio en lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres filtrar por el nombre del día de la fecha actual puedes hacerlo mediante el uso de **[`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname)**.

Tampoco necesitas `LIKE` para ese filtro, puedes hacerlo así simplemente:

```
INSERT INTO `gym`.`registrodiario` 
    (
        `idPagoCliente`, 
        `idCliente`, 
        `idTipoPeriodo`, 
        `inicio`, 
        `final`,  
        `costo`
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM pagosclientes  
    WHERE 
        idCliente LIKE '%$labusqueda%' 
        AND curdate() < final 
        AND LCASE(DAYNAME(NOW())) = 'thursday';
```

Aquí he usado `LCASE` para convertir el nombre del día a todo minúscula.

Esta consulta puede recibir de forma dinámica el valor relativo a `thursday`, pero asegúrate de convertirlo también a minúscula.

> #### ADVERTENCIA SOBRE SEGURIDAD
>
> En cuanto a la seguridad, considera el uso de consultas preparadas, ya que pasar datos de variables
> directamente en las consultas supone un grave riesgo de *Inyección
> SQL*. Recomiendo que leas sobre el tema cuando sea posible.

Comment: En la base tengo un campo que se rellena como CURRENT_TIMESTAMP tiene fecha y hora larga (2019-03-21 19:17:16) sabes como dejarlo que solo sea (2019-03-21)? el campo es autogenerebla el momento de introducir el dato

Comment: @NathanielHumbertoBaldizon esa podría ser una pregunta interesante para tratarla aparte. Es una pena que se pierda la respuesta en un comentario. Sugiero que lo plantees como una nueva pregunta, verificando primero si no se ha preguntado ya. Así tendrás el punto de vista de otros usuarios también. Aunque de entrada diría que si es un campo para saber por ejemplo cuando se creó una fila o cosas así, es mejor dejarlo del tipo `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, porque en ese caso la hora puede ser requerida en algunos escenarios. A nivel de espacio en la BD es lo mismo o casi lo mismo.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247869/current-timestamp-a-fecha-corta    ahi tengo formlulado nuevamente!