# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP a fecha corta

Tags: php, mysql, sql

En la base tengo un campo que se rellena como CURRENT_TIMESTAMP tiene fecha y hora larga (2019-03-21 19:17:16) como puedo dejarlo que solo sea (2019-03-21)? el campo es autogenerable el momento de introducir el dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que has investigado?

Comment: Lo que tengo por el momento es que Current_timestamp me da la fecha con hora largas, y current date me daria corta a como busco pero en phpmyadmin solo me da opcion de poner el campo como CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @alfap ahi puse la imagen que solo me brinda esa opción, he encontrado que debe ser con CURRENT_DATE para la fecha que deseo que es AÑO-MES-DIA pero no me da la opción.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si la intención es que la columna `fechavisita` tome la fecha actual al momento de crear la fila, convertir el tipo de dato de `TIMESTAMP` a `DATE` debo decirte que:

- mediante definición/modificación de tabla no es posible si estás usando MySQL anterior a la versión 8.0.13, tendrías que recurrir a un `TRIGGER` y establecer un plan de actualización de los datos que ya existen.
- mediante definición/modificación de tabla es posible si estas usando una versión de MySQL superior a 8.0.13
- en ningún caso tendría sentido o utilidad querer cambiar una columna de este tipo de `TIMESTAMP`  a `DATE`.

### No es posible en MySQL `8.0.13 -`

Por que la consulta que habría que ejecutar sería la siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE mTable  
MODIFY fechavisita DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

Esta consulta acabaría en el error siguiente:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CURRENT_DATE;

Esto es debido a que los valores que se usan para `DEFAULT` no pueden ser asignados mediante el uso de funciones, o sea, no admitiría asignar la fecha actual mediante el uso de funciones como `CURRENT_DATE, NOW`.

Para asignar valores con `DEFAULT`, la única función permitida es `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` y ninguna otra. Tampoco valdría usar una función que convierta `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` a un formato `YYYYMMDD`.

Esto es lo que dice [el Manual de referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit-old) al respecto:

> #### Manejo de valores predeterminados explícitos antes de MySQL 8.0.13
>
> Con una excepción, el valor predeterminado especificado en una
>   cláusula `DEFAULT` debe ser una constante literal; no puede ser una
>   función o una expresión. Esto significa, por ejemplo, que no puede
>   establecer el valor predeterminado para que una columna de fecha sea
>   el valor de una función como `NOW()` o `CURRENT_DATE`. La excepción es
>   que, para las columnas `TIMESTAMP` y `DATETIME`, puede especificar
>   `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` como predeterminado. Consulte la [Sección 11.3.4,
>   “Inicialización y actualización automáticas para `TIMESTAMP` y
>   `DATETIME`”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

---

### Es posible en MySQL `8.0.13 +`

En cambio, en `MySQL 8.0.13 +` la consulta de modificación sí funcionaría, porque la restricción antes mencionada cambió, [como también indica el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-types-defaults-explicit):

> #### Manejo de valores predeterminados explícitos a partir de MySQL 8.0.13
>
> El valor predeterminado especificado en una cláusula `DEFAULT` puede
>   ser una constante literal o una expresión. Con una excepción, incluya
>   los valores predeterminados de la expresión entre paréntesis para
>   distinguirlos de los valores predeterminados constantes literales...
>
> La excepción es que, para las columnas `TIMESTAMP` y `DATETIME`, puede
>   especificar la función `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` como predeterminada, sin
>   incluir paréntesis. Consulte la [Sección 11.3.4, “Inicialización y
>   actualización automáticas para TIMESTAMP y DATETIME”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

---

### No tiene sentido

Realmente no tiene sentido querer quitar la hora a tu columna, porque aunque la conviertas al tipo `DATE`, MySQL seguirá guardando la hora, pero establecida a `00:00:00`. Eso lo puedes ver fácilmente si creas una columna del tipo `DATE`, cuando consultas esa columna, se mostrará así:

```
22.03.2019 00:00:00
```

Además, en ese tipo de columnas por defecto puede llegar un momento en que la hora también interese. Supongamos un futuro requerimiento que diga: *es necesario saber qué registros se crearon después de las 3 de la tarde*.

Si por algún motivo no interesa presentar la hora, se puede usar en el `SELECT` una función de formato, para traer solamente la fecha, o se puede trabajar por programación si fuera necesario.

En MySQL, sería algo como esto o cualquier otro formato válido según lo que necesites:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mFecha,'%Y%m%d') mFecha FROM mTable;
```

**Salida:**

```
mFecha
--------------
20190322
```

Answer (score 1):

Edita el código desde tu cliente de tu (WAMP o XAMPP), y ubícate en tu `SELECT -- FROM --`, añade un `WHERE`con el siguiente código:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Lo que haces es recuperar los datos para usar el formato *día-mes-año*. De esta forma es que se pueden aceptar los formatos.

Adicionalmente podrías validar la fecha de hoy:

```
Código Anterior = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo tenía la misma duda, pero lo que hice fue cambiar en `phpmyadmin` el `TIMESTAMP` por un `DATE`, en predeterminado iría "ninguno" y en el código hice lo siguiente (`PHP`)

```
?php 
-------(Esto agarra la fecha de tu pc, la "Y" debe ser 
$fecha = date('Y-m-d'); mayúscula para que agarre el año como "2019" y no "19"
luego hacer tu INSERT INTO normal---------
INSERT INTO `tu tabla` ('`campo1`', '`campo2`', '`fecha_actual`') VALUES ('`value1`', '`value2`', '`$fecha`');
?
```

Espero que te ayude esa opción.